# Can't update my mail password on Macbook Air

Tags: mail.app, email, password, gmail

I recently changed my Gmail password, and as expected, the mail app can't log in to that account anymore. It says "Login Failed" in the top right.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to update the password so it works again. When I go to "accounts" in "preferences", there's literally no password field. It lists Description, Alias, Email Address, Full Name, Incoming Mail Server, User Name, Outgoing Mail Server, TLS Certificate. That's it.

When I try to "add account" in the file menu, I type in my info and it of course says that account has already been added.

Is there any way to just wipe out the account and start over? Or is there some other way to update the password?

Edit: Added picture.
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you see? [with details blanked out, of course] For me the password field is right there, unmissable, so I can't imagine what you are seeing. Post it to imgur or similar & add the link in comments & someone can inline it for you, if you're not sure how.

Comment: Added to the post!

Comment: ahh, IMAP I just realised doesn't have the password there, it's in 'Outgoing Mail Server, then edit the correct one from the list & Advanced tab. Mine for iCloud is empty there, so I might not be on the right lines - but worth a look

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to send out emails from your Gmail account using Apple's iCloud as SMTP server which is not correct. Here's what you can do:

Open Mail > Preferences > your Google account > in the dropdown menu select **Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)** > Edit SMTP Server List

Ensure that the settings match the following:

- Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - Requires SSL/TLS: **smtp.gmail.com**
- Port: **465 or 587**
- Requires SSL: **Yes**
- Requires authentication: Yes
- Full Name or Display Name: [your name]
- Account Name or User Name: your full Gmail address (username@gmail.com).
- Password: your Gmail password

More info on Google Support Docs: [Change SMTP settings to check Gmail on other clients](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reconfigure your password by doing that through *System Preferences > Internet Accounts* and select your Google account there.

If you recently changed your Google password, a Google login popup should appear.

Comment: There was no way to change my email password there, either. However, it did allow me to delete the account and start over, so I got it working that way.

Comment: If it's working again, please mark your question as answered.